# Angular vs jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Объясните в чем преимущества Angular перед jQuery, если такие есть. В каких случаях целесообразней использовать ангулар?

Comment: Судя по вопросу (видимо нет понимания работы фреймворка(~ов) должен быть простой ответ:

Фреймворки типа Angular необходимы когда мы разрабатываем относительно сложное приложение, а не сайт. Т.е. когда необходимо оперировать структурами данных, их способом хранения, загрузки, обработки и визуализации. Причем разделение всех этих процессов на отдельные составляющие помогает быстро заменять их реализацию на новую, не затрагивая основную часть.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Я углубляться не буду. Отвечу очень просто.

**jQuery** - это **библиотека**, которая позволяет делать сложные вещи на js простыми способами (в частности, за счёт виджетов и плагинов).

**AngularJS** - это **MVC-фреймворк**, который на себя берёт полностью генерирование страницы с помощью шаблонов и моделей, и управление ей, используя двусторонний дата-биндинг, изменение её, используя логику вашего приложения.

Они - кардинально различаются по целям. Даже сам факт того, что AngularJS в себе уже содержит jQuery (его облегчённую версию [jQLite](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element)), уже говорит о том, что это - совершенно разные вещи, выполняющие разные задачи.

Если совсем просто:

- **jQuery** - это библиотека, чтобы вместо

`document.querySelector('[data-bind="example"]')
    .addEventListener('click', function () { ... }, false);`

писать

`$('[data-bind="example"]')
  .on('click', function () { ... });`

и чтобы это поддерживали все браузеры.

- **AngularJS** - это чтобы сделать single page application (где после клика на каждую ссылку страница не будет перезагружаться полностью, а переход будет происходить сразу) и написать весь Frontend на нём.

Comment: После ответа возникает ощущение, что Angular только для SPA. [Это не так](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15231251/is-angularjs-just-for-single-page-applications-spas).

Comment: По поводу сравнения поддержки браузерами у последнего jQuery (IE9+), разве что у старых версий (1.12-) поддержка IE6-8 есть, а у Angular тоже самое поддержка IE9+ (https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/browser-support.html), у версии 1.2- есть поддержка IE8.
Поэтому с аргументом "и чтобы это поддерживали все браузеры" не согласен.

Answer (score -1):

1. Bindings, особенно двусторонние, в Angular сильно упрощают жизнь по сравнению с jQuery.
2. Декларативность и написание читабельных шаблонов (модификации DOM в jQuery намного менее сопровождаемы и очевидны на первый взгляд).
3. Angular написан с учётом модульности и тестируемости, поэтому содержит Dependency injection.

Comment: реализация связывания не очень и при большом количестве двусторонних - это скорее осложняет жизнь, чем упрощает. Для jQuery есть куча шаблонизаторов. Никто не запрещает писать код с jQuery с учетом модульности и тестируемости. Как видно, все три пункта зависят от мнения конкретного разработчика. А вопросы в которых нельзя дать объективно верного ответа стоит либо отредактировать, либо закрыть.

Comment: Согласен, но то, что описал есть из коробки и не надо использовать что-то дополнительное. Сама библиотека предрасполагает к этому.

Comment: Это все потому, что библиотека тут только jQuery. Поэтому сравнивать набор функций и каркас приложения - несколько некорректно. Особенно учитывая то, что ангуляр использует внутри себя обрезанную версию jQuery, а может использовать и обычную.

Comment: Я не против, чтобы вопрос закрыли или мой ответ дополнили и т.д..
Но всё равно считаю данный вопрос очень полезным, особенно для новичков или тех, кто почти всю жизнь сидел на jQuery.
Не зря на английском SO [тот же вопрос](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18414012/what-does-angularjs-do-better-than-jquery) так популярен.

Comment: и тоже закрыт _closed as too broad_. Кроме того, там немного по другому составлен вопрос, а не просто _Angular vs jQuery_